# simple RC circuit corresponding differential equation

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have an RC circuit as shown below
[image]

unfortunately I have no knowledge about RC solving but I want to obtain corresponding differential equations for V1, V2 and V3. Having in hand differential equation for V1 is enough for now, if anyone can tell me it!!!

Comment: s-domain analysis is one way to go.

Comment: I'll be grateful if you can give me differential equation for only V1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework without effort.

Comment: it's not homework. actually it is a circuit model from a paper which I need to use it for my analysis in my dissertion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deriving 2nd order passive low pass filter cutoff frequency](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152159/deriving-2nd-order-passive-low-pass-filter-cutoff-frequency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Pkdu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In box 1, we're converting our current source into a voltage source and further converting it to its s-domain equivalent.

Then in box 2 we're taking the s-domain source together with the s-domain equivalent of the impedances of the given circuit. (see [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/S-Domain_circuit_equivalents.svg))

Assuming that the capacitances had no voltage across them initially, (i.e. \$V_{0_{C_1}}=V_{0_{C_2}}=0\$, the s-domain circuit is equivalent to that in box 3 where \$V=-V_1\$ and \$R_{\text{equiv}}=\left[\left[\left(R_2+\frac{1}{sC_2}\right) \parallel\ R_L \right]\parallel \frac{1}{sC_1}\right]+R_1=R_1+\left[\frac{1}{R_2+sC_2}+\frac{1}{R_L}+\frac{1}{sC_1}\right]^{-1}\$

Hence $$V_1=-V=-\left(\frac{R_\text{equiv}}{R_s+R_\text{equiv}}\right)\cdot\frac{iR_s}{s}$$

The expression for \$V_1\$ will be a function of \$s\$; applying inverse laplace transform (using [tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=+Inverse+Laplace+transform&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=inverse+laplace+transform+table) is easier) to the equation will give you the differential equation you require.